# Visual Studio not using Visual Studio Command Prompt for post-build events

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, csc

I was wondering why Visual Studio won't do what it's been told as I recognized, that Visual Studio just uses the standard Windows Command Prompt and not its own VS Cmd Prompt.

This results in an

```
'csc' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

error message in the build output window.

So.. is there a way to tell VS to use its own command line tool where csc is usable or do I really have to set additional system variables to get this run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just call out to the thing the normal VSXXXX command prompt uses:

Ex:

```
CALL ""%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
```

(edit: updated as per Hans's comment)

Comment: Well this was the right answer but it didn't work. I can run csc if I start the prompt on my own but even though I got the echo `Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.` in VS the command `csc` results in the error `'csc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.` anyway .. any guess why?

Comment: Ok I was now setting the system variable, restarted VS and did it as.. well.. as one would do it, right?

Comment: Don't use cmd.exe /k, that produces a console window that doesn't close.  With the settings lost when you close it.  Use CALL instead.  Do beware that the .bat file can't guess which .NET version you target.

Comment: @HansPassant Doh! Of course, Hans is right - mea culpa, I completely forgot about that. :P